# How to Un-Select previous selected tab on selecting new tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Div which contains tabs .Now as per my requirement i want to highlight tabs on Selection.Also i want previous tabs to get un-selected on selecting new tab but its not happening here ..

Here is my HTML and Jquery..

```
    <div style="background:lightgray;">
        <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:960px;">
            <ul id="dropdown_nav">
                <li><a id="tab1" class="first" href="#" style="font-family: Candara,Trebuchet MS,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a id="tab2" class="first" href="#" style="font-family: Candara,Trebuchet MS,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">TEAMS</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
           $("#tab1").click(function () {

                //to highlight
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');

            });
            $("#tab2").click(function () {

                 //to highlight
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');

            });
```

Here is the CSS..

```
       .selected
        {
          background:#00a1e4;
          color: white;
        }
```

Now as soon as i select `tab2` i want tab1 to be shown original without highlight.

Thanks..

Comment: Provide a fiddle or Html markup to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for your problem,

```
$("#tab1").click(function () {
    $('.first.selected').removeClass('selected');  //clear previous selected
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');               //to highlight

});
$("#tab2").click(function () {
    $('.first.selected').removeClass('selected');  //clear previous selected
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');                       //to highlight

});
```

---

Looking at your markup, below is a better solution, as writing tab click handler on each ID causes repitative code.

```
$(".first").click(function () {
    $('.first.selected').removeClass('selected');  //clear previous selected
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');               //to highlight

});
```

Comment: Thnaks a lot ! Working

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var tabs = $(".first");

tabs.click(function () {
  tabs.removeClass('selected').filter(this).addClass('selected')
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QJT52/)

Answer (score 0):

your jquery
you can do this via using class

```
$(".first").on('click',function () {

                $('.first').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');

            });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/2sLm6/)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/j9xRx/)**</kbd>

jquery

```
$('ul').on('click', 'a', function () {
    var aElement = $('ul > li > a');
    aElement.removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    return false;
});
```